# How to generate extra static file in webpack

Tags: webpack

I want to generate an extra static file, i.e., a version.json. How do I do that? I see there are some plugins that are supposed to help with generating version files, but they are more complex than I need. I just want to generate a file from a simple string in-memory. I looked at CopyWebpackPlugin, but I don't see a way to specify a file from memory. Is there an easy way using an existing mainstream plugin?

Comment: Create your own plugin... https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-plugin/#src/components/Sidebar/Sidebar.jsx

Answer (score 0):

I ended up coming across the `generate-json-webpack-plugin` plugin which is very convenient for creating a json file in the webpack build.